# Unity Custom Inspector with enum dropdown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm tryin to make a dropdown options who enabled a few things. For example I've got an enum (dropdown) with the next options "Array, List, Stack, Queue" if I select "array" only fields of type array are going to be displayed on inspector, if I select "list" only fields of type List are goint to be displayed, and so on. How can I to do that?, btw it's a serializable class, it looks like this:

```
public enum DataContainer
{
    Array, List, Stack, Queue
}

[System.Serializable]
public sealed class ClassWithFields
{
    public DataContainer containerType;
    public GameObject[] go_A;
    public List<GameObject> go_L;
    public Stack<GameObject> go_S;
    public Queue<GameObject> go_Q;
}

public class OnInspectorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ClassWithFields classWithFields;
}
```

EDIT: I want to apply something similar to a scriptableObject too, but even a simple thing like a "boolean toggle" doesn't work on scriptableObjects.

Comment: Well, you're not using `DataContainer` anywhere, sooo...its not going to show in the inspector.

Comment: 20 hours later and I didn't realize I didn't write that in the example, thanks.